# How to extend Joomla! to my custom PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a php file i created. I want to extend all the Joomla! classes to that file. Or i at least want to be able to use Joomla's class for accessing the database within my PHP file. How can I extend the functionality that way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: difficult with out space and punctuation marks.

Comment: All i wanna know is what files i need to require or what i need to extend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put these lines on top of your php file

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../' );   // should point to joomla root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

now you can use all joomla classes here

Comment: Thank you. This is all i needed to know. I appreciate it very much. I don't understand why some people just can't help but put ignorant comments. And this will work for Joomla! 1.7 right?