# Check Username Availability Not Working on Joomla Site

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I am just adding a new feature to my Joomla TPJOBS component although it's not a good/complete/active component but just I'm adding a user name Availability checker but its not working because it may be due to in this component.

Check the website : http://tinyurl.com/72rx7af

[Click on Check availability which is not working]

My Joomla Component Directory is : \public_html\components\com_tpjobs\

You can get the files here http://forum.joomla.org/download/file.php?id=88705

Editing tpjobs.html.php(exiting) and username_validate.php (created)

My Javascript AJAX Code : which is under tpjobs.html.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
  //function to create ajax object
  function pullAjax(){
    var a;
    try{
      a=new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    catch(b)
    {
      try
      {
        a=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
      }catch(b)
      {
        try
        {
          a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch(b)
        {
          alert("Your browser broke!");return false
        }
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function username_validate()
  {
    site_root = '';
    var x = document.getElementById('username');
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    user = x.value;

    code = '';
    message = '';
    obj=pullAjax();
    obj.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if(obj.readyState==4)
      {
        eval("result = "+obj.responseText);
        code = result['code'];
        message = result['result'];

        if(code <=0)
        {
          x.style.border = "1px solid #FF0084";
          msg.style.color = "#FF1A00";
        }
        else
        {
          x.style.border = "1px solid #008C00";
          msg.style.color = "#73880A";
        }
        msg.innerHTML = message;
      }
    }
    obj.open("GET",site_root+"username_validate.php?username="+user,true);
    obj.send(null);
  }
  //-->
</script>
<style>
#username{border: 1px solid #000;}
</style>
```

PHP File under the TPJobs component

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');


    $user = strip_tags(trim($_REQUEST['username']));

    if(strlen($user) <= 0)
    {
      echo json_encode(array('code'  =>  -1,
      'result'  =>  'Invalid username, please try again.'
      ));
      die;
    }

    $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); //get database object
    $db->setQuery("Select username FROM #__users where username = '$user'")

    $db->query(); //do actual query

    $result = $db->getAffectedRows(); //return affected rows

    if($result)
    {
      echo json_encode(array('code'  =>  1,
      'result'  =>  "Success,username $user is still available"
      ));
      die;
    }
    else
    {
      echo  json_encode(array('code'  =>  0,
      'result'  =>  "Sorry but username $user is already taken."
      ));
      die;
    }
    die;
?>
```

Comment: I tried you form out of curiosity, entered a wrong captcha it seems, and when I went back with the link provided all the fields (all mandatory, btw) were blank. Now I hate you. :-)

Comment: Anyway, Firebug tells me `missing ; before statement
eval("result = "+obj.responseText);`

Comment: it's not a good/complete/active component

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues that i notice

first one is that your ajax url doesn't seems to be correct.
component folder name is com_tpjobs and in your url it is components/tpjobs
it should be components/com_tpjobs/.....

second point is that while calling a file directly through ajax it doesn't load joomla framework so you cannot use joomla class and functions in it.

to get this you have to include few line at the top of your ajax file
see here [How to extend Joomla! to my custom PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829036/how-to-extend-joomla-to-my-custom-php-file/8833128#8833128)

Comment: What would be the site root for the Javascript ?

    site_root = '';

Comment: you have to generate you javascript dynamically so that you can use joomla variables to initialize javascript variable.