# Extending Drupal Functionality to Custom PHP Page

Tags: php, drupal

I have Drupal 7 site which is working fine. I added a custom PHP page to my site in the root directory of it. I want to extend the Drupal application functionality to that one page so that I can have access to the different Drupal classes and basically extend Drupal through my page. What includes do I need at the top of my page to be able to access the Drupal application as if I were within the Drupal site?

Comment: You might be interested in: [Drupal's code registry](http://drupal.org/node/350780) via [Class Autoloading (Drupal Answers)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15086/class-autoloading) - Also who told you that you extend drupal by placing some `.php` file into your site's root directory? I mean, it's easy, you place a file there and then you ask here because you tried so much already?

Comment: I've done it in Joomla! [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833128/1086938) and I'm looking for a Drupal equivalent.

Comment: I'm no Drupal 7 expert, but if I remember Drupal 6 correctly, I would go and locate the index.php file and take a look in there how drupal itself does this. Probably this gives the hints to the includes you need to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Your code here
```